# Convert Any Date Inserted To ISO Format Without The Timestamp In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, iso

I want to know how can convert any date that entered to text box using JQuery Datepicker to the ISO date format without the Timestamp. At the below you can find the code sample that I have used.

```
$("#to_date").datepicker({  maxDate: new Date(),dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
$("#from_date").datepicker({  maxDate: new Date(),dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
```

But when I pass these dates to a JSON web service it shows is invalid date. So what should I do?

Thanks & regards,
Chiranthaka

Comment: First off, what format does the JSON service expect?

Comment: Is `dateFormat` a `datepicker` http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ `option` or `method` ? Thanks

Comment: The ISO format does has a Timestamp with it..[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp)... What exactly is the format that the server is expecting..?

Comment: The JSON service is expecting the yy-mm-dd format.

Comment: I think dateFormat() is a method.

Comment: As the date I want only the date not whole date with the time stamp. I want the time stamp removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From original documentation:
Display the date in ISO format. Produces "2007-01-26".

```
$.datepicker.formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", new Date( 2007, 1 - 1, 26 ) );
```

Comment: If I edited the above statement as `$.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", new Date("#to_date") );` the date-picker in the HTML page does not pop up. This #to_date is the ID of the text box that the **To Date** will be inserted.